# Creating makefile and build file for c++ program

Tags: makefile

I 'm new to linux, I have read many tutorials on how to make a `makefile` but couldn't create it. I m trying to write a `makefile` which creates a new file copy the content of `format.cpp` in the new file and launch that file in `sublime`.
e.g if I type `make hello.cpp`, then it will create a new file `hello.cpp` and will copy the content of `format.cpp` into this `hello.cpp` and launch this file in `sublime`.

Secondly, I m trying to write a `build` file which compiles and runs that c++ file.
e.g currently I m compiling and running my c++ file as

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp
./hello < input.txt > output.txt`
```

Please Help!!!

The code for makefile is:

```
src?=a.cpp
```

`new:
    rm -f *.o *.out*
    cp format.cpp a.cpp
    subl a.in a.cpp`

The code for build is:

```
in: $(src)
g++ -std=c++14 -fmax-errors=1 -DLOCAL -O3 $(src) -o a.out
./a.out < input.txt > output.txt
subl output.txt
```

If we dont type any file name then it will open a.cpp by default

Comment: What have you tried?  Post what you have in your makefile currently.

Comment: How do you do the first part from the command line? That is, if you want to launch `hello.cpp` in `sublime`, what command do you use?

Comment: @ODYN-Kon, please find the code in the updated post